# Locate/Find .exe file (javaw.exe) then use elevate.exe and run jar

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, executable-jar, javaw

I tried to make the title as descriptive as possible, but im basically trying to locate `javaw.exe` because when I launch my JAR cmd only finds `java.exe` but the prompt window is ugly and I don't want it there.

What works:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

What I'm trying to do

```
javaw -jar myJar.jar
```

What also works:

```
JAVAWPATH\javaw.exe -jar myJar.jar
```

I'm trying to make the program adapt to any computer automatically, since I don't know if javaw will always be in the same location.

So I have managed to locate a bunch of "javaw.exe" files using

```
WHERE /R c:\ *javaw.exe
```

I want to select one of the returned paths and set some kind of string variable with which I can then: `elevate MYstringPATHtoJAVAW -jar myJar.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a batch script which locates the java instalation folder through the registry:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@ECHO OFF

:: Export java settings from registry to a temporary file
START /W REGEDIT /E %Temp%.\java.reg "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft"



:: Find java location
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ('TYPE %Temp%.\java.reg ^| FIND "INSTALLDIR"') DO SET JAVA_HOME=%%B
SET JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
SET JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:\\=\%
SET JAVA_HOME

:: Get java version
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ('TYPE %Temp%.\java.reg ^| FIND "CurrentVersion"') DO SET JAVA_VERSION=%%B
SET JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:"=%
SET JAVA_VERSION
SET JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:.=%
SET JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:_=%
SET /A JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION%

:: Delete temp file
@DEL %Temp%.\java.reg /S /Q > NUL 2>&1

:: Check java version compatibility
IF %JAVA_VERSION% LSS 16020 (
ECHO.
ECHO YOU NEED AT LEAST JAVA WITH VERSION 1.6.0_20 -- this is just an example echo.
GOTO :EOF
)

PAUSE
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I've used this as a [base](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/country3_nt.txt).But it might not work properly if the installed java is a 64bit (yes, I must update this script...) , but it can be updated easy.Hope this will help you.