# If Statement in Batch file executes if and else block

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to write a Batch file that starts a java application. If Java is not installed on the users computer the application is started with a provided java version depending on the operation system.

The Problem is that both the `IF` and `ELSE` part of the statement are execute as if the statement did not exist.

```
IF DEFINED %JAVA_HOME%(

Echo staring with installed java version

) ELSE (
REM check if computer is running 32 or 64 bit
REM code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556009/en-us

Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0
REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt
Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt

If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    Echo starting with 32bit java
    Set JAVA_HOME=bin\java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
) ELSE (
    Echo starting with 64bit java
    Set JAVA_HOME=bin\java64\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
)

DEL checkOS.txt
DEL StringCheck.txt
)

START %JAVA_HOME%\javaw [java arguments]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF DEFINED %JAVA_HOME%(
```

You need a space before the opening bracket here.And for checking if a variable is defined you should not use **%**es. Try this->

```
IF DEFINED JAVA_HOME (
```

And java does not set %JAVA_HOME% variable on windows systems.Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744678/locate-find-exe-file-javaw-exe-then-use-elevate-exe-and-run-jar/12788535#12788535)

Comment: Thanks, the `%`es were the problem.
looking for JAVA_HOME is sufficient in my case.